# Storing username and password in Git

Tags: git

When I do

```
git push
```

I get the command prompt like

```
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

then I enter my username manually like

```
Username for 'https://github.com': myusername
```

and then I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and I get prompt for my password

```
Password for 'https://myusername@github.com':
```

I want the username to be written automatically instead of manually having to type it all the time.

I tried doing it with `xdotool` but it didn't work out.

I have already done

```
git config --global user.name myusername
git config --global user.email myemail@gmail.com
```

but still it always asks for me to type manually

Comment: you know you can store credentials with git, right?

Comment: You should set up an SSH key on GitHub and use that instead.

Comment: @DiegoRoccia yes, mentioned that as well in the question, but it doesn't help.

Comment: You can use as `git config credential.helper store` described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403407/git-asks-for-username-every-time-i-push 
In this case you do not store the password in clear text in the origin URL, but in a file in you profile. (Also not encrypted)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Actually what you did there is setting up the author information, just for the commits. You didn't store the credentials. credentials can be stored in 2 ways:

1. using the git credential functions: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store
2. change the origin url to "https://username:password@github.com".
3. a third alternative is to use an ssh key (as @StephenKitt said).
   For github configuration, you can find all needed information [in GitHub help page](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/)

Comment: adding username and password to origin url is not good becouse of security reasons but if you feel yourself in secure then this is best path.

Answer (score 62):

In Terminal, enter the following to enable credential memory:

```
$ git config --global credential.helper cache
```

You may update the default password cache timeout (in seconds):

```
# This cache timeout is in seconds
$ git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
```

You may also use (but please use the **single** quotes, else double quotes may break for some characters):

```
$ git config --global user.name 'your user name'
$ git config --global user.password 'your password'
```

Comment: how to cache forever?

Comment: @R.Gurung Use  `git config credential.helper 'store` in that case, but _be aware_ that this stores your `git` credentials on disk in plain-text, without any encryption whatsoever. (`~/.git-credentials`)

Comment: Note, the above snippet should be --global flagged as well and close its opening `'` such that it reads: `git config --global credential.helper 'store'`

Comment: If you want the config to be specific of a website (e.g. only for github.com, but not gitlab), you have to use `git config credential.https//github.com ...` instead of `git config credential.helper ...`

Answer (score 11):

Copied this from [git scm](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store)

```
$ git config credential.helper store
$ git push http://example.com/repo.git
Username: <type your username>
Password: <type your password>
[several days later]
$ git push http://example.com/repo.git
```

[your credentials are used automatically]

Answer (score 4):

In linux (Ubuntu 18.04) the username / password [can be saved](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store) in the file `~/.git-credentials`, just edit the file to use your new username / password.

The file format is quiet easy to understand and manipulate, each line contains credentials for one user / domain, in the following format:

```
https://<username>:<password>@github.com
https://<username2>:<password2>@bitbucket.com
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [git-credential-oauth](https://github.com/hickford/git-credential-oauth), included in [many Linux distributions](https://repology.org/project/git-credential-oauth/versions).

> *No more passwords! No more personal access tokens! No more SSH keys!*
>
> git-credential-oauth is a Git credential helper that securely authenticates to GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket and Gerrit using OAuth.
>
> The first time you push, the helper will open a browser window to authenticate. Subsequent pushes within storage lifetime require no interaction.